# xcode: convert iphone to ipad issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to convert an iphone project to an ipad but having a build issue for the new ipad version.

I was able to convert the iphone project to ipad 3.2  and run it.  When I run it it shows up in the ipad simulator as an iphone app. (Which is fine)

I then changed the simulator to iPad 4.1 with the new target of iPad

When I do a build it erorrs with the following message:

ld: library not found for -lBump

---

What I did:

1) under project menu I selected Upgrade current target for ipad and selected two apps
2)  Switch my current target to the new ipad target that xcode created
3) hit build and run but fail

What should I check?

Comment: You could check your others question and set the good answers to reward developers whom answered you.

Comment: Oh Ok. Sorry. I dont see any buttons to click when I view my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the Lib Search Path was incorrect. Changing this corrected the problem.